# Validating docker-compose yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any easy way to verify the syntax, etc of a docker-compose file (`docker-compose.yml` aka `fig.yml`) without having to run docker proper?

I am trying to add a quick check to my build / test pipeline to verify my compose files.

Comment: Note that I know of, but https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/129

Comment: You could put your build pipeline inside a container where you actually test with proper docker. Kind of like docker itself. Could that work?

Answer (score 222):

Meanwhile this has been added to docker-compose as [docker-compose config](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/config/). Validating your file now is as simple as
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml config`. As always, you can omit the `-f docker-compose.yml` part when running this in the same folder as the file itself or having the [COMPOSE_FILE environment variable pointing to your file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#/composefile).

Comment: When spitting out an error, it does not even give a line number... why? would that be so difficult?

Comment: This is near useless. It just returns an error "unsupported config option" in my case. It doesn't tell me what the unsupported option is or provide a line number.

Comment: In April '23, the output seems to have improved, at least with docker compose instead of docker-compose (docker compose version 2.16). I got a notice "services.app_com.networks.mynetwork must be a mapping", a precise and sufficient information about the faulty node.

Answer (score 4):

In the directory where the `docker-compose.yaml` file is run this command:

```bash
docker-compose config --quiet && printf "OK\n" || printf "ERROR\n"
```

you will get as the output either

> OK

or for example:

> parsing /path/to/the/docker-compose.yaml yaml: unmarshal errors:
> line 40: mapping key "image" already defined at line 29
> ERROR

If you want to check `docker-compose.yaml` file that is not in the current dir then use the flag `-f`:

```bash
docker-compose -f /path/to/the/docker-compose.yaml config --quiet && printf "OK\n" || printf "ERROR\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use pre-commit framework https://pre-commit.com/#usage and this hook https://github.com/IamTheFij/docker-pre-commit.

Install pre-commit and add these lines to `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```
repos:
  # Docker hooks
  - repo: https://github.com/IamTheFij/docker-pre-commit
    rev: v2.0.0
    hooks:
      - id: docker-compose-check
```

Then run `pre-commit run --all-files`.

Comment: This is a neat suggestion, but it's for Dockerfiles, not docker-compose.yml.

Comment: wdym? it's literally said `docker-compose-check`